# What's the best way to put in a database sensors data's

Tags: web-service

I have not already started to try but I'm a good webmaster and I'm just asking which way is more suitable for sending and keeping data from sensors and I/0 state in a database.

Here are some points:

- Post versus get
- MySQL or others types
- Security layers
- Graphics render of data's (google API?)
- PHP, ruby, JavaScript...
- Able to send data request's to Arduino's
- Ethernet shield, wifi, I2c ???
- Access via Android app...

Anyway, the goal here is to know pros and cons of integrate all my Arduino through database.

Comment: This is *really* vague, and really only tangentially related to arduinos at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your skills and what you have in your Arduino "box".
Let's assume you have an ethernet or WiFi shield.

I would go with a PHP script (I'm a PHP dev, but any language will fit) that accepts POST requests sent by the board and store them in a SQLite db.

**Why SQLite instead of MySQL?** Well, it's just a matter of data portability. You copy the SQLite file or send it via email and you're done: there are plenty of clients out there to read your db, in *nix based machines is frequently integrated in the OS.

MySQL requires a sort of "infrastructure" to be written/read.